# Get filtered range by a specific criteria

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I want to get in a specific sheet (different from my source sheet) a filtered range of my source data. 
It seems to work but the result data are like this:

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@39888471

[Ljava.lang.Object;@4d696b89

[Ljava.lang.Object;@143e260

[Ljava.lang.Object;@7970a23
```

and It wuold be:

```
RU  lppp    ooo oo  o

RU  2425    iiii

RU  83  iii

RU  24  iiii
```

This is my code:

```
function MyFunction() {
var sourceData = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Prova");
var destinationData = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Copia di Prova");
var lastRow = sourceData.getLastRow();
var data = sourceData.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 1).getValues();
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
 if (data[i][0] == "RU") {
   var filteredRow = sourceData.getRange(i+1,1,1,5).getValues();
   destinationData.appendRow(filteredRow);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filteredRow` is a a two-dimensional array.

[appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) takes a one-dimensional array as argument.

Hence, your call to append a row should looke like this: `appendRow(filteredRow[0])`